# Find instances of overridden method in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Say I have the following:

```
public class TextField {
  private String value = "";
  public String getValue() { return value; }
}
```

And:

```
public class TextField2 extends TextField {
  public String getValue() { return value; }
}
```

Is there any way in Eclipse to search for **only** instances of the `getValue()` method called on a TextField2 object?  I'm assuming the answer is no, but figured I would ask.

Comment: `TextField2` object or `TextField2`-typed expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by selecting the overriden method, pressing the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. Or by selecting *Search --> References --> Workspace* from the menu. In the Search view that shows the result, click on the button with the arrow icon at the top right of the view and select **References to Overriden**.

[image]

But as @Sotirios implied in the comment, this would not detect references by variables declared of type `TextField` which may be instances of the subtype `TextField2` at runtime.

Comment: is this still relevant? I don't see `References to Overriden` in eclipse Neon

Comment: @user7294900 The option exists in Eclipse Oxygen as shown in the added image.

Comment: does not work for me. I have e xactly one call to a toString() in my Test.class, if I do a search on toString() and then 'references to overriden' I still get dozens of hits on other toString() methods from other unrelated classes.