# How do I find usages of method implementation in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I want to find usages of a normal method in java it is fairly easy and straightforward **CTRL-SHIFT-G** .

However if this method has a *super* definition, or implementation, then eclipse will show me usages of all types in the hierarchy types.

For example, if I have a **toString()** method on my class, I would only be interested in finding exactly where this toString() of this class was being called, instead eclipse gives me every single ancestor toString in the project (ie **Object.toString()**).

How do I find only specific usages to my class? And not usages of parent classes like **Object.toString()** ?

Comment: could you please release this bounty.

Answer (score 21):

**`Alt + ctrl + h`** should give you exactly, what you are looking for.

Updated with screenshot from my workspace as some people are facing issue in following it:

[image]

Comment: It still find occurrences of Object's toString() in Eclipse Neon

Comment: it shouldn't, I am using eclipse mars currently and it works/worked (with older versions) perfectly.

Comment: it's a correct answer: in eclipse right click and then choose `Open Call Hierarchy`... upvoted :)

Comment: @HalayemAnis But if use it on a specific method as `new MyClass("aa","").toString();` it will return all `Object.toString()` method usages

Comment: @ user7294900 I just tried to replicate same as you suggested but it worked fine for me. I am using jdk8, eclipse mars2, java perspective. I selected 'toString()' on line new MyClass().toString() and it gave me single result. Make sure you haven't overridden any default key bindings.

Comment: this is returning me a call hierarchy. I am not sure this is right. If I have a class ABC and create a toString() method, then have class XYZ call toString() on an instance of ABC, it should only give me that one single reference. If I use Alt+CTRL-H, then it gives me references to Object.toString() throught the project which is not what I want.

Comment: @OliverWatkins the exact same scenario is giving me single result. There is something behaving differently on your setup. I am using windows7, java 1.8, eclipse mars2 in java perspective. can you give it a try on another machine/eclipse?

Comment: let me try again

Comment: same problem, my call hierarchy lists TestA.toString() being referenced by dozens of classes, instead of exactly one instance.

Comment: @OliverWatkins definitely, something is different in your environment. I just uploaded screenshot from my workspace to show it exactly mimics your use-case. I would suggest you to cross check your key bindings in eclipse.

Comment: thanks for the screenshot. Add an object.toString() to your method like this : public void testMethod() { new A().toString(); new Object().toString(); } ... does this Object.toString also get referenced now in the call hierarchy? In my case all toStrings() on Object classes are also listed

Comment: Thats the correct behavior. if you are selecting 'new Object().toString()' then it will show all the references to Object's toString. It will show 100s of results because Object is base class of all classes in java. that's not eclipse; its core java :)

Comment: thats a shame. makes it impossible for me to test my scenario. If I have a toString() method in my custom class, then it will also list toString() of super classes like Object.class. I have thousands of classes, so I always get 100s of hits :( It's a shame Elcipse isn't smarter.

Comment: @OliverWatkins if you have a custom toString() method then its not at all an issue. Your scenario is a special case where you are doing 'new Object().toString()', doing call hierarchy on this is bound to produce large number of results as Object is base class of all classes in java. Also, its not a shame on eclipse. It is performing its job perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @manouti [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600262/find-instances-of-overridden-method-in-eclipse/30600426?noredirect=1#comment89076798_30600426),
To show when using the overridden method only follow the steps:

Search by Java the method as `com.package.MyObject.toString()`

[image]

And after in search result screen click on the right arrow to the left and check `References to Overridden`

[image]

Comment: does not work for me. I have e xactly one call to a toString() in my Test.class, if I do a search on toString() and then 'references to overriden' I still get dozens of hits on other toString() methods from other unrelated classes.

Comment: @OliverWatkins in Java Search you Limit To: References?

Answer (score 0):

After having the same problem as many others in the comments (Eclipse shows references to Object.toString()) I have found a way that seems to work correctly:

Go to outline from your custom class, right click on your toString() implementation and References -> Project. This displays only references to said implementation.