# How do I find usages of class in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am looking for a way to find class occurrences in other classes.
I know I can look for occurrences of a specific method in eclipse: [How do I find usages of method implementation in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816494/how-do-i-find-usages-of-method-implementation-in-eclipse)

If I select a method and hit "Open Call hierarchy" eclipse shows me all occurrences of this method.
I would have expected that this works for classes, too. However, this does not work for me. If I have the following scenario:

```
public class A {
  // ...
}
public class B {

    private A a;
}
```

I want to find all classes, where my class A is used. Intuitively, I do a right-click on class A and hit "Open Call Hierarchy. However, this does not show me class B, where class A is used.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to right-click on the class A file - references/Project

You can also use Ctrl + Shift + G

EDIT: This answer your question?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.